# Finding average error of the data

Tags: plotting, functions, function-construction

Considering I have some data, and I want to fit the data to a linear fit and find the average error from the linear fit, how can I do that using Mathematica?

I have

```
temp = WeatherData[location, "MeanTemperature", {start, end, "Day"}];
Show[ListPlot@Partition[Reverse@temp["Values"], 2, 1], Plot[line, {x, 0, 40}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

Which generates

[image]

How can I find the average error of this linear fit?

Comment: What about error?

Comment: if you mean an example with LinearModelFit, it doesn't cover my case.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57423/make-a-scatter-plot - I need do that with the data I get from the link

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16457/room-for-mike-and-oska

Comment: I don't believe we do need a room, not that I don't want to be in a room with you ;o) But just provide the data or the code to create them.

Comment: The data is weather information for last 10 years, i don't have any other info

Comment: Well, you can provide the _Mathematica_ code producing the data can't you?

Comment: temp = WeatherData[location, "MeanTemperature", {start, end, "Day"}];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16458/discussion-between-mike-and-oska).

Comment: If, for example, `dat = Table[{x, Sin[x] + RandomReal[{-.2, .2}]}, {x, 0, 10, .1}];` (because the code you gave needs a location and other parameters and I don't know, nor want to learn, how to set that) then eg `mdl = NonlinearModelFit[dat, a*Sin[b*x] + c, {a, b, c}, x]` finds a model and you can find for example the variance like so `Variance[dat[[All, 2]] - mdl /@ dat[[All, 1]]]`.

Comment: mike, show the LinearModelFit code you tried that fails.

Comment: @Mike, `fit["EstimatedVariance"]` gives the variance.  The documentation refers to many other properties and measures that are available, if you're after something else.

Comment: @acl lm = LinearModelFit[
   Partition[Reverse@QuantityMagnitude[temp["Values"]], 2, 1], x, x];

Comment: @Michael E2
Does it give the AVERAGE error?

Comment: @Mike a) that code doesn't work unless I know `temp`, b) is it too much to ask what doesn't work with `LinearModelFit` or the `NonlinearModelFit` example I gave?

Comment: @acl I don't want to paste all my code here :) don't you mind on a chat-room so that I could explain?

Comment: @Mike What do you mean by average error? Square-root of the variance? `Mean[Abs@fit["FitResiduals"]]`?

Comment: @Michael E2 
I mean following: in case if i would do it by paper or another framework, i would calculate the module distance of every single point from the best linear fit and then combine them to have the average (mean value).

Comment: @Michael E2
My final point is to use that info to build a function that will take the temperature of yesterday and will give as a result the average temperature of the day.

Comment: I believe those displacements are called [residuals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors_and_residuals_in_statistics) and are given by `fit["FitResiduals"]` or by the formula acl used inside `Variance` in his first comment.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is `0`, if the question is what is the value of `Mean[fit["FitResiduals"]]` and `fit` is a linear, least-squares fitted model.

```
data = WeatherData["London", "Temperature", {{2004, 1, 1}, {2013, 12, 31}, "Day"}];
normaldata = Partition[Reverse[data["Values"][[All, 1]]], 2, 1];
fit = LinearModelFit[SetPrecision[normaldata, Infinity], x, x, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
lfit["FitResiduals"] // Mean
(*
  0.*10^-19
*)
```

Other possibilities:

Mean of the absolute residuals.

```
lfit["FitResiduals"] // Abs // Mean
(* 1.455345158021296804 *)
```

Standard error (root-mean-square of the residuals).

```
lfit["EstimatedVariance"] // Sqrt
(* 1.862702601613853043 *)
```