# Make a scatter plot

Tags: plotting, function-construction

Considering I have weather data for last 10 years for London, how can I make a scatter plot that will show the previous day's temperature as a function from today's temperature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html) the data into pairs of successive values.  [`Reverse`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reverse.html) the data to make the previous day the dependent variable. Examples:

```
Partition[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 2, 1]
(* {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}} *)

Partition[Reverse@{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 2, 1]
(* {{5, 4}, {4, 3}, {3, 2}, {2, 1}} *)

Reverse /@ Partition[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 2, 1]
(* {{2, 1}, {3, 2}, {4, 3}, {5, 4}} *)
```

*Mathematica*'s weather data.  [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) will plot the points.

```
data = WeatherData["London", "Temperature", {{2004, 1, 1}, {2013, 12, 31}, "Day"}];

ListPlot@Partition[Reverse@data["Values"], 2, 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]